# Hide the highlight that appears on the referenced line in the CLion

Tags: c++, ide, highlight, clion

[image]

In the CLion code editor, when clicking on a specific line of code, that line gets highlighted with a glowing light, which can be distracting for me. How can I hide this light when clicking on a specific line?

"I want to hide the highlight from the referenced line in the CLion code editor."

Comment: Note that you can also take a screenshot of the screen of your pc instead of clicking a pic using a camera. See [How to Take a Screenshot on a Windows PC](https://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Microsoft-Windows)

Answer (score 0):

The option is called `Caret row` [image: option page with Caret row]